# Server-side validation of custom rejection reasons fails to recognise nonsense consisting entirely of Braille Pattern Blank as invalid

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits, whitespace

Trying to submit a custom rejection reason (when reviewing suggested edits) that consists entirely of whitespace understandably results in an admittedly hilarious error message displayed after the server-side validation fails:

[image: "Sorry buster, we are going to need a valid reason" error message]

However, it is possible to construct the whole message consisting entirely of the [Braille Pattern Blank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_pattern_dots-0) character (U+10240<sub>10</sub>, U+2800<sub>16</sub>), a [well-known way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415084/11407695) of going around the minimum allowed characters limitation in comments and post titles.

The server-side validation of the reason fails to detect that, resulting in the reason being registered ([the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31632583) was worthy of immediate rejection, in case anyone is worried about potential harm of the experiment):

[image: review result notice with the empty reason accepted screenshot]

Can the server-side validation for custom close reasons please be tightened to disallow this?

Comment: Why? Is someone abusing this? Is it really something to spend developer time on?

Comment: @Makyen no, not really, but still worth a report. Since it is quite unlikely that *any* report unless made about a recent rollout is addressed in earlier than 6 to 8, I am not worried much about draining developer time on that - it's clearly a low-priority thing.

Comment: Possibly a dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415084/should-we-make-this-character-whitespace

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine definitely related, even linked to it in the question. I suppose *all* validation on SE does not account for BPB

Comment: Oh, didn't see you linked it ^^" Carry on

Comment: Let's keep this. I can also use it when I send the suspension messages to the users who are caught abusing it.

Comment: ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀, @CodyGray

Comment: It's ok.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: "sorry buster" ? Must be a legacy error message, it's from a couple of decades ago.

Comment: @Gimby it seems go be veeery old: I found references to it on MSE (but, strangely, not on MSO) as far back as [2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129064/786798)!